# Word Count in between XML tags

Tags: python, xml

The '[data_science_assignment.txt](http://www.uva.nl/binaries/content/assets/programmas/information-studies/txt-for-assignment-data-science.txt?3015083536432)' that contains three articles from LA Times in a semi-structured format. The tags in the collection dictate the beginning and the end of an article (`<doc>` and `</doc>`), the article id, the headline of the article and the main text (`<text>` and `</text>`).

I trying to code a class that can preprocess and store the LA Times articles.

The methods of the class should take as an input the LA Times articles collection, extract each article in the collection, and construct a hash table, the key of which is a word (in the collection) and the value a linked list of all the document that contain this word, and the count of the word in each document.

E.g the word “the” appears in all three articles, 20 times in the first, 34 times in the second, and 12 times in the third

**Desired Output:** the -> [1, 20] -> [2, 34] -> [3, 12]

**Current Output:** the -> [1,16] -> [2,16] -> [3,16]

Problem: I unable to properly count the words between `<text> </text>` tags while ignoring `<p></p>` tags. How do I improve my current code for an accurate word count.

```
    __author__ = 'Sam'
import lxml.html as LH
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

from collections import Counter


doc = ET.parse("data_science_assignment.txt")
root = doc.getroot()
# Initialise a list to append results to
# root = html.fromstring(doc)
art1 = ""
art2 = ""
art3 = ""
i = 0
# Loop through the pages to search for text
for page in root:
    id = page.findtext('docno',default='None')
    text = page.findtext('text/*',default='None')
    # text = page.attrib.get('text',None)
    if i==0:
        art1 = text
    elif i==1:
        art2 = text
    else:
        art3 = text
    i+=1


# article1 = art1.split()
# article2 = art2.split()
# article3 = art3.split()
# print article1
# print (len(article1) + len(article2) + len(article3))
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
dict3 = {}
words = []
words.extend(art1.split())
words.extend(art2.split())
words.extend(art3.split())
# print len(words)

for word in words:
    if word.lower() in art1:
        # print word.lower()
        if word.lower() in dict1:
            dict1[word.lower()] += 1
        else:
            dict1[word.lower()] = 1

for word in words:
    if word.lower() in art1:
        # print word.lower()
        if word.lower() in dict2:
            dict2[word.lower()] += 1
        else:
            dict2[word.lower()] = 1

for word in words:
    if word.lower() in art1:
        # print word.lower()
        if word.lower() in dict3:
            dict3[word.lower()] += 1
        else:
            dict3[word.lower()] = 1

# for k,v in dict1.iteritems():
#     print k,v
#Get words present in all the articles
dict4 = {}
check = []
for word in words:
    if word.lower() in dict1.keys() and word.lower() in dict2.keys() and word.lower() in dict3.keys():
        if word.lower not in dict4:
            dict4[word.lower()] = "-> [1," + str(dict1[word.lower()]) + "] -> " + "[2," + str(dict2[word.lower()]) + "] -> " + "[3," + str(dict3[word.lower()]) + "]"
for k,v in dict4.items():
        print(k,v)


dict5 = {}
# #get words present in only first two articles
for word in words:
    if word.lower() in dict1.keys() and word.lower() in dict2.keys() and word.lower() not in dict3.keys():
        if word not in dict5:
            dict5[word.lower()] = "-> [1," + str(dict1[word.lower()]) + "] -> " + "[2," + str(dict2[word.lower()]) + "]  "# + "[3," + str(dict3[word.lower()]) + "]"
for k,v in dict5.items():
        print(k,v)
```

Comment: Do you get three times the same number for any other word as well?

Comment: yes for all words I get the same number

Comment: Good questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to improve yours adding a sample of the input..

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I have a good question

Comment: @usr2564301 yes for all words I get the same number

Comment: Indeed but input sample is needed to reproduce your scenario, so it's good but not verifiable.

Comment: You get three times the same value because you **check the same file three times**: `if word.lower() in art1:`. (It is not the only problem, of course, because your count is also off.)

Comment: @LuisMuñoz thank you for the correction I have added a link to the input textfile in data_science_assignment

Comment: @usr2564301 How should I check the three different files?

Comment: @usr2564301 And how do I increase my count accuracy

Comment: Not checking `art1`, `art1`, and then `art1` ought to get you started.

Comment: I have changed it to art 1, art2, and art3

Comment: But I still get the same number for all three articles

Comment: You should use a different variable for each article `words1.extend(art1.split())`, `words2.extend(art2.split())`. You use the same so I guess you are getting the count  of all articles. Also, there's a length tag, might help to check your total count `<length>
<p>
1206 words 
</p>
</length>`

Comment: @LuisMuñoz My code now only check the first <p></p>

Comment: @LuisMuñoz how do I ignore the <p></p> tags

Comment: Check the xpath used in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some clean up, this is my take on the issue:

Changed xpath parser and expression
Created 1 variable per article
Counts are not all correct so word splitting debug is needed

```python
import lxml.html as LH
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

from collections import Counter

doc = etree.parse("test.xml")
# Initialise a list to append results to
art1 = ""
art2 = ""
art3 = ""
i = 0

art1 = doc.xpath('string((//text)[1])')
art2 = doc.xpath('string((//text)[2])')
art3 = doc.xpath('string((//text)[3])')

dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
dict3 = {}
words = []
words1 = []
words2 = []
words3 = []
words1.extend(art1.split())
words2.extend(art2.split())
words3.extend(art3.split())
words.extend(words1)
words.extend(words2)
words.extend(words3)

for word in words1:
    #if word.lower() in art1:
        # print word.lower()
    #print("'%s'" % word)
    if word.lower() in dict1:
        dict1[word.lower()] += 1
    else:
        dict1[word.lower()] = 1

for word2 in words2:
    #if word.lower() in art2:
    # print word.lower()
    if word2.lower() in dict2:
        dict2[word2.lower()] += 1
    else:
        dict2[word2.lower()] = 1

for word3 in words3:
    #if word.lower() in art3:
        # print word.lower()
    if word3.lower() in dict3:
        dict3[word3.lower()] += 1
    else:
        dict3[word3.lower()] = 1

#Get words present in all the articles
print("Words present in all articles\n")
dict4 = {}
check = []
for word in words:
    if word.lower() in dict1.keys() and word.lower() in dict2.keys() and word.lower() in dict3.keys():
        if word.lower() not in dict4:
            dict4[word.lower()] = "\t-> [1,%d] -> [2,%d] -> [3,%d]" %(dict1[word.lower()],dict2[word.lower()],dict3[word.lower()])

for k,v in sorted(dict4.items()):
        print(k,v)

print("\n\nWords present in articles 1,2\n")
dict5 = {}
# #get words present in only first two articles
for word in words:
    if word.lower() in dict1.keys() and word.lower() in dict2.keys() and word.lower() not in dict3.keys():
        if word not in dict5:
            dict5[word.lower()] = "\t-> [1,%d] -> [2,%d]" %(dict1[word.lower()],dict2[word.lower()])

for k,v in sorted(dict5.items()):
        print(k,v)
```

Result:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->

Words present in all articles

a       -> [1,27] -> [2,4] -> [3,23]
all     -> [1,1] -> [2,2] -> [3,3]
an      -> [1,6] -> [2,1] -> [3,3]
and     -> [1,34] -> [2,3] -> [3,51]
as      -> [1,6] -> [2,1] -> [3,5]
at      -> [1,4] -> [2,3] -> [3,5]
be      -> [1,4] -> [2,1] -> [3,7]
by      -> [1,6] -> [2,2] -> [3,8]
for     -> [1,7] -> [2,5] -> [3,9]
in      -> [1,26] -> [2,3] -> [3,31]
is      -> [1,16] -> [2,1] -> [3,12]
of      -> [1,56] -> [2,6] -> [3,54]
one     -> [1,4] -> [2,1] -> [3,1]
so      -> [1,4] -> [2,1] -> [3,1]
that    -> [1,11] -> [2,1] -> [3,16]
the     -> [1,94] -> [2,12] -> [3,65]
their   -> [1,1] -> [2,2] -> [3,6]
then    -> [1,1] -> [2,1] -> [3,1]
these   -> [1,1] -> [2,2] -> [3,4]
to      -> [1,22] -> [2,3] -> [3,35]
with    -> [1,7] -> [2,1] -> [3,4]


Words present in articles 1,2

accident.       -> [1,1] -> [2,1]
entire  -> [1,1] -> [2,1]
from    -> [1,1] -> [2,1]
story   -> [1,3] -> [2,1]
```

Comment: Your method ignores the <p></p> tags

Comment: why should they be considered?

Comment: Your method also duplicates the word count

Comment: but the  word "the" should only be counted between <text> tags

Comment: But it  is 94 for the first article. Which is incorrect

Comment: Yes, I said that in my answer which fixes several issues in your code anyway. Up to you to consider it acceptable.

Comment: It's really weird! I replaced all"the" with "xxxxxx" and got the correct count!

Comment: i tired .split(' ') but it didn't change much

Comment: Counts are correct :p. Manually counting failed for me because I did not passed all strings to lower. Put text of first article in a file with one word per line and run this command. It confirms counts are ok `cat doc1.txt | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn -k1,1 | less`